# Android studio 3.1.2 cursor disappering

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-3.1

I recently updated my android studio from 2.3 to 3.1.2 after updating while syncing gradle cursor disappears and tick black horizontal line comes when i click on editor.[image]

I searched on SO. As SO answers i checked my date and time of PC. and re-installed my OS and installed Android studio again but still i'm facing this issue.

Do any one know why this issue is coming?